# not able to change volume in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

I am unable to change volume and the devices are not shown in sound setting in root ,

but in guest session ,it is working well.

Answer (score 1):

First, goto "System Settings", then, "Sound", under the Hardware category. You should see the slider, which you can change the volume.